# How to change volume of Python's playsound

Tags: python, playsound, python-playsound

I'm using `playsound` library to successfully play an mp3 file:

```
import playsound
playsound.playsound('audio.mp3')
```

However, it's too loud relative to the other sound sources on my computer. How do I decrease the volume?

I don't wish to use `pydub` or `pygame` since I'm having other issues with those two libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there doesn't seems to be any documentation about this functionality, the only way to me is to change the application volume.

[Changing the application volume could technically be done with ctypes](https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-win32/12912).

However, while I'm not aware of the issue pygame poses, it seems quite trivial to implement only as a mixer:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("path/to/file")
sound.set_volume(0.5)
sound.play()
```